# Get the pieces of a date from a string

Tags: ios, string, cocoa-touch, date-formatting

How would you get the substring of a string that is dynamic? By this I mean that I am retrieving tweets and I want to extract different parts of the return value into a Month String, a Year `int`, a day `int`, and a time `int`. Here is what I am retrieving:

```
Sun Nov 17 00:15:47 +0000
```

How would I split it up even if the given value would change over time, as the tweet is on a index path of multiple table view cells, and the value of the creation date would be different for each one of the cells?

Answer (score 1):

Your string represents a date, so the first thing you should do is convert it to an `NSDate` using an `NSDateFormatter`.

Then you can get the various elements of the date by creating an `NSDateComponents` instance via [`-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-BBCCAFIG), and accessing its `month`, `day`, and whatever other properties you need.

Comment: @prnk28 - There are thousands of examples here of how to use NSDate formatter.  Use a little initiative.